# Get next occurrence of a weekday if not found in desired week

Tags: javascript, date, recurrence

How can I come up with an algorithm to find out the very next occurrence of a weekday if not found in the desired week. For example following is the screenshot of the calendar. There is no `Tuesday` in first week of `April`. I need an idea how can I go for the next `Tuesday` in the next week if not present in the given week?
[image]

Below is my algorithm which is working fine in getting any week's selected weekday. I just want to add two conditions in it to iterate back and forth in the case when weekday is not present in the given week.

```
for(var ind=0; ind<=between.length; ind++){
   if (new Date(between[ind]).getMonthWeek() === baseDtWk && new Date(between[ind]).getDay() === baseDtD) {
       datesToBeMarked.push(between[ind]);
       console.log(" :Date: " + between[ind] + " :Week: " + new Date(between[ind]).getMonthWeek());
       console.log("Date entered : " + new Date(between[ind]));
   }

}
```

In above code `baseDtWk` & `baseDtD` contains the week and day.

**Week** is an integer from `1 to 5`.

**Day** is an integer from `0 to 6` representing weekday from `sun` to `sat`.

`for-loop` iterates over all the array elements & push the elements into another array which has same week and weekday in a month. So ideally it is fulfilling the purpose in happy scenario, where every time weekday is available. Unlike the above case. Any ideas, guidance will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code it looks like you already have the structure in place just need to know how to utilize it.

I'm going to slightly modify your `if condition` as shown below.

```
  for(var ind=0; ind<=between.length; ind++){
      var thisDt = new Date(between[ind]);
      if (thisDt.getMonthWeek() === baseDtWk && thisDt.getDay() === baseDtD) {
          datesToBeMarked.push(thisDt);
          console.log(" :Date: " + between[ind] + " :Week: " + thisDt.getMonthWeek());
          console.log("Date entered : " + new Date(between[ind]));
          }
     }
```

Just by adding a `var thisDt = new Date(between[ind])` you can get much cleaner code than before.

**1.** Now look at your code carefully you are already scanning each date by its week and weekday in your `if-condition`. And qualified element goes to `datesToBeMarked[]` array.

**2.** You need to introduce another `if-condition` which will walk through the `between[]` array and will scan every `base day` (You call it base which is the first element in your `between[]` array). Now the `if-condition` will look like as below.

```
  for(var ind=0; ind<=between.length; ind++){
      var thisDt = new Date(between[ind]);
      if (thisDt.getMonthWeek() === baseDtWk && thisDt.getDay() === baseDtD) {
          datesToBeMarked.push(thisDt);
          console.log(" :Date: " + between[ind] + " :Week: " + thisDt.getMonthWeek());
          console.log("Date entered : " + new Date(between[ind]));
      }else if(thisDt.getDay() === baseDtD && thisDt.getMonth()!==new Date(datesToBeMarked[ind-1]).getMonth()){
                   //some magic needs to be done here
              }
  }
```

**3.** What is happening above in the `else-if`? It is checking your already selected `Tuesday` with the next element. If it is coming in the same month then reject it. Otherwise let it come inside the `if-condition` to see the magical move. :)

**4.** Lastly here inside your `else-if` you need a function to be called which will find you the `next occurrence` of the `Tuesday` if it is not in place initially in the first week as shown in your picture above.

**5.** Function for finding the day will look like as written below. And you are all set hopefully. 
Following function needs to be replaced inside your `else-if` with this comment `//some magic needs to be done here`.

```
function nthDay(nth, weekday, month, year) {
    var nthDate = new Date(year, month + ((nth <= 0) ? 1 : 0), 1);
    var dayofweek = nthDate.getDay();
    var offset = weekday - dayofweek;
    nthDate = new Date(year, month + ((nth <= 0) ? 1 : 0), nthDate.getDate() + (offset + (nth - (offset >= 0 ? 1 : 0)) * 7));
    if (nthDate.getMonth() !== month) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return nthDate;
    }
}
```

**6.** Happy Coding :)